# Dynamic DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC NO ACTION RESULT CREATE()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, cascadingdropdown, actionresult

I CANNOT CREATE CASCADING DROPDOWN IN ACTIONRESULT CREATE, ONLY IN ACTION RESULT INDEX IT WORKS

THERE GOES THE CODE

**CONTROLLER**

```
public class PessoasController : Controller
    {
        private GestarkContext db = new GestarkContext();

        // GET: Pessoas
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Gabinetes = new SelectList(db.Gabinetes, "GabineteId", "Nome");

            var pessoageral = db.Pessoas.Include(a => a.gabojecto).Include(a => a.nivelojecto);
            return View(pessoageral.ToList());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getDistricts(int gbtID)
        {
            List<Departamento> DepartamentoList = db.Departamentoes.Where(p => p.GbtId == gbtID).ToList();

            return Json(DepartamentoList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**VIEW INDEX - IT WORKS HERE**

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#Gabinetes').change(function () {
            var gbtID = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "getDistricts",
                data: "{gbtID:'" + gbtID + "'}",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#DepartamentoList').empty();
                    $('#DepartamentoList').append('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Departamento</option>')
                    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                        $('#DepartamentoList').append('<option value=' + d.DircId + '>' + d.Depto + '</option>');
                    });

                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert('error occured');
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<h2>Lista de Funcioários Registrados</h2>
<br />
<label class="col-md-2 control-label">Gabinete</label>
<div class="col-md-5">
    @Html.DropDownList("Gabinetes", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Departamento</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select id="DepartamentoList" name="DepartamentoList" class="form-control"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Visualizar Formulário", "Index", "Principal", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }) | @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar Novo", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })  | @Html.ActionLink("Exportar em Excel", "ExportToExcel", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
</p>
```

...........
[image]
NOW ON VIEW CREATE DOES NOT WORK

I write the code as I do in index, but it doesn't work

I NEED YOUR HELP PLEASE